# How to develop RMI-based applications in netbeans 6.9.1?

Tags: java, rmi, netbeans-6.9

Please tell me, is there support for developing RMI based applications in netbeabs IDE. It would be great if you could point out a tutorial or two. I tried googling, but sadly couldn't find anything very helpful!

regards

shahensha

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Netbeans doesn't support this anymore.  Look at this thread for more details:
http://forums.netbeans.org/topic2493.html&highlight=

Also check this forum:
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=930

-Jim